# Django Rest Framework: Retrieving object count from a model

Tags: json, routes, django-rest-framework

Does anyone know how can I successfully retrieve the object count of a model, in JSON format, and how I need to configure my routing? I'm trying to achieve this using a APIView and returning a Response formatted by JSONRenderer.

## UPDATE:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer, JSONPRenderer))
def InfluenciasCountView(request, format=None):
    influencia_count = Influencia.objects.count()
    content = {'influencia_count': influencia_count}
    return Response(content)
```

Here's the route I'm using:

```
url(r'^influencias/count/$', views.InfluenciasCountView, name='influencias-count')
```

Answer (score 13):

Check out [this snippet of code](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#how-the-renderer-is-determined) (the second one). If this does not suit your need, please add some of your code (for better understanding).

**UPDATE**

For routing, DRF offers a [default router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers#defaultrouter) for each view. This means that you can have the following configuration in your *urls.py*: (using the example from the previous link)

```
url(r'^users/count/$', views. UserCountView.as_view(), name='users-count')
```

Then, when you access the URL `your_base_url/users/count/` you will see something like `{'user_count': 10}`.

**UPDATE 2**

The entire code should look like this:

```
class UserCountView(APIView):
    """
    A view that returns the count of active users.
    """
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user_count = User.objects.count()
        content = {'user_count': user_count}
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: AdelaN, this snippet is perfect. I've tried to use exactly this one. But couldn't write the correct route for it. Could you help me?

Comment: Hi! It didn't work for me. I've updated my question above with the code I'm using, so you can check the details. Basically, I'm getting a 404 (Not Found) when I try to access the route, like this:

`HTTP 404 NOT FOUND Content-Type: application/json Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS Vary: Accept
{
    "detail": "Not found"
}`

Comment: It didn't work. Anything I should do differently besides using the GenericAPIView?

Comment: Yes, you should change the method signature

Comment: I did it. It's like below right now. Any changes to the route?

`@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer, JSONPRenderer))
def InfluenciasCountView(request, format=None):
    influencia_count = Influencia.objects.count()
    content = {'influencia_count': influencia_count}
    return Response(content)`

Comment: Does it work now? I re-checked the docs, and APIView should also work. Could you please post a more detailed code to pastebin? And also errors, if you get any.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question. You can check it. I'm getting a 404 right now:

`HTTP 404 NOT FOUND Content-Type: application/json Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS Vary: Accept
{
    "detail": "Not found"
}`

Comment: I just try the code above and it works for me (see update). Can you show me what is the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: I'm using `http://example.com/influencias/count`
I get a DRF page, with the 404 inside.

Comment: Could you provide a print screen or a stack trace? I really don't know why it isn't working for you...

Answer (score 8):

I am using `routers` from REST Framework to build my URLs.  I tried above code but doesn't get it working.  One of the problems is I cannot get `/count/` into the router endpoints.

I checked DRF document (3.8.2) and found that there is a (new?) `@action` decorator (I was using 3.7.7 and it doesn't have it).  So, here is my full solutions:

1. Upgrade DRF to 3.8.2 (or above) in `requirements.txt` (or `PipFile` if you using that).
2. Add a new action `count` method to the ModelViewSet
3. Update `get_permissions` to include the newly added action `count`

Here is my `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows recommend to be viewed or edited.
    """
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend,)
    search_fields = ('title', 'body',)
    filter_fields = ('status', 'type')

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ('list', 'retrieve', 'create', 'count'):
            return (AllowAny()),
        if self.action in ('update', 'partial_update'):
            return (IsAdminUser()),
        return (IsAdminUser()),

    @action(detail=False)
    def count(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        count = queryset.count()
        content = {'count': count}
        return Response(content)
```

- To query count of posts: `/api/posts/count/?format=json`
- To query count of published: `/api/posts/count/?format=json&status=published`

One of the important thing here is to use the queryset from `filter_queryset(...)`, rather than `Post.objects.all()`.

**UPDATE**

Since `count` is common, I created a mixin for that.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CountModelMixin(object):
    """
    Count a queryset.
    """
    @action(detail=False)
    def count(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        content = {'count': queryset.count()}
        return Response(content)
```

To use it, just add CountModelMixin to your ModelViewSet (also support nested ModelViewSet).

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, CountModelMixin):
```

If you use permissions, also add `'count'` to the list of granted action.